# AZCopy: Summary along with detail from /V: parameter

Tags: azure, powershell, azcopy

I have the following that is working fine and producing a text file attached to an email with the following summary as an example:

```
[2019/07/04 10:40:16] Transfer summary:
-----------------
Total files transferred: 1
Transfer successfully:   1
Transfer skipped:        0
Transfer failed:         0
Elapsed time:            00.00:00:03
```

I'd like to incorporate the /V: parameter also, but I'm not sure how to have the above summary and the detail from the /V: parameter within the same file. Is this possible? Azcopy 8.1 is being used.

```
$azPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy\"
Set-Location $azPath

$StorageAccountName = "#"
$StorageAccountKey = "#"
$ContainerName = "#"

$SourceFolder = "c:\test2"

$DestURL = "https://$StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$ContainerName"
$Result = .\AzCopy.exe /source:$SourceFolder /dest:$DestURL /BlobType:block /destkey:$StorageAccountKey /Y /S /XO

$Result | Out-File Result.txt
Send-MailMessage -From 'SQL Alerts <sqlalerts@#>' -To 'SQL Alerts <sqlalerts@#>' -Subject 'Backups (#): Copy to Azure' -Attachments .\Result.txt -SmtpServer 'smtp'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to incorporate the /V: parameter also, but I'm not sure how
>   to have the above summary and the detail from the /V: parameter within
>   the same file. Is this possible?

Actually, you do not need to generate a separate result `txt` file, if you specify a relative path following option `/V`, such as `/V:test/azcopy1.log`, then the verbose log is created in the current working directory within a subfolder named `test`. Refer to more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#generate-a-log-file).

For example `$Result = .\AzCopy.exe /source:$SourceFolder /dest:$DestURL /BlobType:block /destkey:$StorageAccountKey /Y /S /XO /v:test/azcopy1.log`. Azcopy will create a log file in your current path `$azPath`. The log file automatically includes the summary information.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that Nancy. The problem comes now where it keeps appending to the log file on each run. Do you know a way of generating a new log file each time, that I can then attach as a file to the email command?

Comment: The easy way is to change a new file location when you want to generate a new log.